# Access Denied in Aure Portral after creating an AD B2C Tenant

Tags: azure-active-directory

I created an AD B2C Tenant in the legacy Azure portal. When I click the link that takes me to the new Azure portal to continue managing my new Tenant I get an "Access Denied" error on the blade, followed by the message:

You do not have access

Looks like you don't have access to this content. To get access, please contact the owner.

Does this have anything to do with the fact that my Microsoft account (that I used to manage Azure) is also tied to Office 360?

Comment: Hi elabs, there are some timing issues with the portal. Can you close and open the browser and go to that link again and give it another shot?

Comment: I tried closing the browser all the way down, opening it again and going to that link again. As far as I can tell it was the same result. This time the CorrelationId was: 5946a1d1-31bf-42f9-a11e-1e46aaf8ca2b

Comment: Suddenly the error has changed:

Comment: Verify B2C feature failed: {"message":"CorrelationId: caddecd3-e7d5-44ca-8b97-f3f3cb13451a; Your tenant XXXX.onmicrosoft.com' is not authorized to use b2c functionality. Please ensure your tenant is whitelisted"}

Answer (score 0):

elabs - a few questions for you:

1. when you say your MSA used to manage Azure is tied to your O365 subscription, do you simply mean that you have both an MSA and a AAD account with the same name?  what do you mean that your accounts are tied?
2. What OS are you seeing this issue on?
3. are you sure your signed in with an MSA or Work Account
   How to Find out - from the old portal use CTRL+ALT+A and look at EMAIL Address; You'll see either (Org) or (MSA) at the end.
4. What is the exact error message and the URL where the error is received.  Do you see a correlation ID or Request ID along with the message?

I've tried every avenue possible to reproduced this issue that I know and simply can't get the result you encountered.

Chris

Comment: Thanks for reaching out! Here are the answers to your questions:

Comment: 1. I don't really know how my Microsoft Account (an old Hotmail account that I used when I originally signed up for Azure) got tied to my O365 account. All I know is that I always log into Azure with my Hotmail MSA and one day, after logging in, I started to see my O365 email address instead of my Hotmail address in the upper-right corner of the screen. So somehow the two accounts are associated.  

2. Windows 10 Edge. I have also seen it in Chrome.  

3. In the old portal I do see my 0365 email address and I see (MSA) after it.

Comment: 4. I don't see any correlation ID or request ID but here is the URL:
https://portal.azure.com/?Microsoft_AAD_B2CAdmin=true&r=1#blade/Microsoft_AAD_B2CAdmin/TenantManagementBlade/id/XXXX.onmicrosoft.com

In that URL I replaced my AD name with XXXX.

I do notice something that I didn't notice before. Now, in the new portal, if I look up in the upper-right corner, it says I am logged in as my other AD account, the older non-B2C account. It doesn't appear to give me an option to change what I am logged in as.

Comment: Oh! I see there is a notification that contained an error message. Here it is (I replaced my sensitive info with XXXX, YYYY and ZZZZ):

Verify B2C feature failed: {"message":"CorrelationId: f1d173ce-dd10-46b8-850e-79fe14c6a395; User 'live.com#XXXX@YYYY.com' needs to be an administrator of ZZZZ.onmicrosoft.com' in order to access this functionality"}

Comment: And the email address it's listing in that error is my O365 address.

Comment: Any ideas about what this problem is?

Comment: Suddenly the error has changed to:
Verify B2C feature failed: {"message":"CorrelationId: caddecd3-e7d5-44ca-8b97-f3f3cb13451a; Your tenant XXXX.onmicrosoft.com' is not authorized to use b2c functionality. Please ensure your tenant is whitelisted"}